# why does grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection() return empty array?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I need to use data from selected row. But in my controller I can't get access to it, because

```
var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()
```

returns empty array - [ ]

I also tried another way as suggested here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153545

> We use selectedRows = grid.getSelectionModel().selected . It returns
>   MixedCollection of the selected rows. Then you can use MixedCollection
>   methods to get different selected Models. Like first(), getAt() etc

but still I get empty MixedCollection. You can see on the picture that one row is indeed selected, than why can't I get access to it? I use ajax proxy in the store if that matters. Also, I am trying to get selected row in the toolbar button "click" event handler. Here is the code of my controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: [
    'user.List',
    'user.Edit'
],
stores: [
    'Users'
],
models: ['User'],
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'button[action=update]': {
            click: this.editUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateUser
        }
    });

},
editUser: function(button, eventObj) {
   this.getSelected();
   //...
  },

getSelected: function() {
  var grid = Ext.widget('userlist');
  var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
  console.log(selectedRecord);
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.widget` does not query for an existing instance of a component in the DOM, but it creates a new instance of the component of `userlist`. So use `Ext.ComponentQuery` instead of it to find existing instances of components.
Better way - use refs:

```
 refs: [
    {
        ref: 'userList',
        selector: 'userlist'
    }
 ]
```

and you can easily use `this.getUserList()` to fetch userlist grid

```
var me = this,
    grid = me.getUserList(),
    selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! Although I figured it myself right before you posted your answer. Still, very appreciate the effort.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)